# Sliding images loaded by append()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Got an annoying bug i can't fix. 
I append a div and put the slider markup inside

```
    $(article_box).append('[MARKUP]');
    $('#screenshot-carousel').carouFredSel({
        responsive: true,
        // scroll: { fx: "crossfade", duration: "1500" },
        items: {
            width: 580
        },
        auto: false,
        prev    : { 
            button  : ".event .prevPhoto",
            key     : "left"
        },
        next    : { 
            button  : ".event .nextPhoto",
            key     : "right"
        }
    });
```

Here markup is:

```
<div class="photo-block" id="'+id+'">
<a href="#"><i class="icon-red icon-in-nav icon-remove"></i></a>
<div class="controls">
<a href="#" class="prevPhoto">&nbsp;</a>
<p class="slides-counter"><span id="the_num">0</span> из <span id="out_of">0</span></p>
<a href="#" class="nextPhoto">&nbsp;</a></div>

<ul id="screenshot-carousel" class="fixclear">
<li><a class="prettyPhoto_transparent" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/fileuploader/index.html?iframe=true&amp;height=600"><img src="/images/quotes/addImages600.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
<li id="additional"><a class="prettyPhoto_transparent" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/fileuploader/index.html?iframe=true&amp;height=600"><img src="/images/quotes/addImages600.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

What i get: the code inserts the markup, and i can see it in browser code viewer (images are there and i can open them in separate tab), but i can't see images in slider. Slider doesn't show slides, actually. All i see is control buttons. There is no bug shown in console , so the code seems to be clear, but what's wrong with showing slides/images?

Comment: can't make it) how do i place slider script there?

Comment: If the code inserts the mark-up, are you sure you are able to access it?  The code needs to exist at the time the page is loaded, or you will need to bind it (or identify with `target.id` or the like).

Comment: Sable, please, show me how to bind it in my case. Actually, i can't clearly understand how binding can work here.

Comment: @user3005840, You need to post the javascript code to insert the mark-up.

Comment: The code works, but i can't see images. When i look into code in browser i see that when i click 'next' it goes next, but i don't see images absolutely